# how to redirect to whatsapp on iOS in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, whatsapp, flutter-dependencies

What happens is that I made an app with a button that redirects to `whatsapp` the problem is that in Android if it works and not in iOS, I have done it with the normal method, I think you have to put something in an `iOS` file but I don't know That is,

**Thanks.**

```
ListTile(
    leading:  Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.headset,color: Colors.black,),
    title: Text('Centro de ayuda '),
    onTap: () async => await launch("https://wa.me/${numero}?text=Hola mi nombre es "+prefs.name+' y necesito ayuda con mi orden de Timugo')            
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Flutter launch WhatsApp.

**INSTALLATION:**
First, add flutter_launch_whatsapp as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

In iOS add the following Info.plist :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

**Example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_launch/flutter_launch.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void whatsAppOpen() async {
    await FlutterLaunch.launchWathsApp(phone: "5534992016545", message: "Hello");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("Open WhatsApp"),
            onPressed: () {
              whatsAppOpen();
            },
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above reference from:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launch

**OR**

You can try below code:

```
var whatsappUrl ="whatsapp://send?phone=$phone";
await canLaunch(whatsappUrl)? launch(whatsappUrl):print("open whatsapp app link or do a snackbar with notification that there is no whatsapp installed");
```

Comment: the version of package are no support for kotlin

Comment: is the second solution helped you?

Comment: Please mention which solution helped you and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: the second solution  helped me .Thanks!